# How to create an auto SMS bot on RingCentral

Tags: sms, ringcentral

I want my app to send auto SMS after a call has been made including summary for example of a delivery or invoice simple summary.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate your SMS service after a call you can use any programming language of you choice. RingCentral offers APIs for both call and sms text messages and you can implement that automation through coding.

You can start reading API reference first to start with.

Check the call API docs here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Control/createCallOutCallSession.

And sending SMS API here

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/SMS/createSMSMessage

If you use Java, you can first call via API and than use SMS API including the invoice summary and implement it via Java ***SDK***.

RingCentral already have different ***SDK*** and you can use those to implement the automation.

Ref https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/sdks